# Javascript if - else if inside switch using ("#id").length

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Code edited. Apologizes for the incomplete first code**
I've this code that takes input from the user, and it appends an image that matches that input. What I want to do is to set different buttons (200 aprox.) to append a different image if other button is pressed. The approaching I'm doing for this is to target the first if, within the first switch case, with the ("#id").length condition.
This is a short example of my code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <section id="section">
    <input id="input">
    <button id="1"></button>
    <button id="2"></button>
  </section>

 <div id="div"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var str;
$("#1, #2").click(function () { test(); });
});

var input = ['a','b','c'];

function test() {

var interval = setInterval(match, 1);
$("div").html("");
str = $("input").val().toLowerCase();
var i = 0;    

function match() {

    var imgs = ["<img src='https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-v2N2hPY33pc/V488gHu5aWI/AAAAAAAAHFM/loGVDK5OlGcft5UUz8-AHZjAd3E7OlZjACLcB/s1600/colorful-background-with-waves.jpg' alt='0'>",
                "<img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c8/Widget_icon.png' alt='1'>"];            

    if (i < str.length) {

      switch (str[i]) {

        case input[0]:


            if ($("#1").length){
            $("div").append(imgs[0]);
          i++;
          break;    

            }else if ($("#2").length){

                $("div").append(imgs[1]);
          i++;
          break;
            }

    }

  else {
    clearInterval(interval);
    $("input").val("");
  }

}
}
```

Now, I've managed to make the if work, it shows the image, but if I press the second button, the else-if never works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: looks like you are missing a `}` from the `test()` function... do you get any errors on the console?

Comment: First of all `(("#1").length)`  should never have worked. You dont have the `$` to target the element

Comment: Your JavaScript code is incomplete. Can you please update your question to provide a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) -- it's hard to work out what's wrong in semi-functional code. It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: `("#1").length` is always `2`

Comment: The inner if condition is always true (or truthy), because `("#1").length` is `2` - you're testing the length of the string `"#1"`. The HTML shown doesn't include any `<input>` elements, so `$("input")` won't match anything. As an aside, you can say `$("#1, #2").click(test);`, you don't need the anonymous function wrapping the call to `test()`.

Comment: @nnnnnn, thank you for those points. now. i thought to use the $("id").length to confirm that the id exists, so if exists, then append the image. is there a better way to run my if using the ID of each button?

Comment: Well nothing in your code tests which of the two buttons was clicked. Your `switch` statement is testing the value of the input element.

Comment: Buttons will always run the same function, but I want to append different images according the id of those buttons. Hence the intention to use those if/else if.

Comment: oh i think i get where you're going

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I can't for the life of me figure out what you're trying to do with this code, but here is a working version of it...

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var str;
  $("#1, #2").click(function () { test(this); });
});
var input = ['a','b','c'];
function test(caller) {
  var interval = setInterval(match, 1);
 var i = 0;    
  $("div").html("");
  str = $("input").val().toLowerCase();

  function match() {
    var imgs = ["<img src='https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-v2N2hPY33pc/V488gHu5aWI/AAAAAAAAHFM/loGVDK5OlGcft5UUz8-AHZjAd3E7OlZjACLcB/s1600/colorful-background-with-waves.jpg' alt='0'>","<img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c8/Widget_icon.png' alt='1'>","<img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ec/Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg/100px-Mona_Lisa%2C_by_Leonardo_da_Vinci%2C_from_C2RMF_retouched.jpg' alt='2'/>","<img src='https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/11/Corythucha_ciliata.jpg/120px-Corythucha_ciliata.jpg' alt='3'/>"];
    if (i < str.length) {
      switch (str[i]) {
        case input[0]:
            if (caller.id == "1") {
             $("div").append(imgs[0]);
              i++;
              break;    
            } else if (caller.id == "2") {
              $("div").append(imgs[1]);
              i++;
              break;
            }
        case input[1]:
            if (caller.id == "1") {
             $("div").append(imgs[2]);
              i++;
              break;    
            } else if (caller.id == "2") {
              $("div").append(imgs[3]);
              i++;
              break;
            }
      }
    } else {
      clearInterval(interval);
      $("input").val("");
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="input"/>
<button id="1">1</button>
<button id="2">2</button>
<div></div>
```

Comment: that did it. Really appreciate the help. Would cast my upvote, but I can't yet.

Comment: I think you should be able to mark it as the correct answer.